# Is it possible to see the content of the "Send to Apple" crash report after closing it?

Tags: crash, logs

My app crashed, and I just took a screenshot before closing the window.
Instead of the screenshot, I really should have copied the whole log...
I can't reproduce the crash, and really want to see the rest of the details.

**QUESTION:** Can I get the full details of the Problem Report, even after I have closed it?

Or is it too late, and it is lost forever?

[image: Send to Apple]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those informations are stored in **Console** application under *Diagnostic and Usage Information*. Here's screenshot:

[image]

You can also find them in:

```
~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/
/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/
```